# Nginx reload an angular application

Tags: angular, nginx

My config for my Angular 6 app:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    server_name localhost;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires       0;
    add_header    Cache-Control  private;
    add_header    Cache-Control  must-revalidate;

    location / {
        add_header    Cache-Control  no-store;
        add_header    Cache-Control  no-cache;
    }

    location /assets/fonts {
    }
}
```

When I push F5 I get "404 Not Found"

If I change config to:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
        expires       0;
        add_header    Cache-Control  private;
        add_header    Cache-Control  no-store;
        add_header    Cache-Control  no-cache;
        add_header    Cache-Control  must-revalidate;
    }
}
```

My page reloads successfully.

But I need to configure the cache settings for /assets/fonts. How to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: What if you add `location /assets/fonts{...` to the second config?

Comment: David, it's work, but why? Post you answer, I check it as right answer. New config:
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
        expires       0;
        add_header    Cache-Control  private;
        add_header    Cache-Control  no-store;
        add_header    Cache-Control  no-cache;
        add_header    Cache-Control  must-revalidate;
    }
    location /assets/fonts {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
        expires       0;
        add_header    Cache-Control  private;
        add_header    Cache-Control  must-revalidate;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first config did not work because the location block was used, which contained no rule.

To achieve what you want, it could work like this without having to add a 2nd try in the `/assets/fonts` location

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
        expires       0;
        add_header    Cache-Control  private;
        add_header    Cache-Control  no-store;
        add_header    Cache-Control  no-cache;
        add_header    Cache-Control  must-revalidate;
    }

    location /assets/fonts {

     root /usr/share/nginx/html; #instead of using try_file
     #Add your headers here
    }
```